# How to run a url 1000 times at a same time?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services

I want to run a url 1000 times at a time.

Suppose I have an url www.examle.com/home.php?id=24. When user hit the page then several functions will execute. Some of functions hits database like insert/update/fetch results. Now I want to check if 1000 of my users hits my url at a same time then will my functions execute properly or not ?

Is there any tools or some way to test it ?

Comment: Apache Bench, Gatling, JMeter, there's plenty of performance testing tools that will do this for you

Comment: I thought writing my own scripts would be awesome, but you simply can't do that simultaneously. You can open let's say 4 or 8 at once. Depending on your cpu actually. So I also used mentioned tools in the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options, my choice is [Siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/)
of course there are many alternatives, have a look at [this list](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/opensource-performance-testing-tools.html) and see what suits you

**if you are using Linux install like this**

```
$ apt-get install siege
```

and use like this

```
$ siege -d1 -c1000 http://www.example.com/home.php?id=24
```

**if you are using Windows, follow the instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/siege-windows/)**

- Download [siege-windows-3.0.5.zip](https://siege-windows.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/siege-windows-3.0.5.zip)*
- Extract to C:\siege-windows and you're done.
  if you want to place siege other then directory above, rename and move siege configuration file siege-windows\etc\siegerc to C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME.siegerc (Windows 7) it is very important the file .siegerc must be started with the dot "."

Benchmark Test Example

test benchmark http://127.0.0.1 with concurrent thread (connection) 10 for 60 seconds

```
siege -c10 -t60s http://127.0.0.1
```

* This is not my file and is not on my website. I take no accountability or responsibility for it's contents

Comment: Can you tell me how to install Siege ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`ab -k -c 1000 -n 10000 http://example.com/`

By issuing the command above, you will be hitting http://example.com/ with 1000 simultaneous connections until 10 thousand requests are met. It will be done using the keep alive header.
After the process finishes the 10 thousand requests, you will receive feedback on stats. This will tell you how well the site performed under the stress you put it when using the parameters above.

Answer (score -2):

In Python try this:

```
import webbrowser
for x in range(1000):
    webbrowser.open('http://example.com')
```

Comment: But by using a `for` loop your connections will be sequential, not simultaneous.

Comment: Opening 1000 browser tabs or windows isn't going to end well.